# GNU make behaves different on another machine

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've created a makefile for GNU make 3.80 which works fine on my main development machine running Windows. I've some experience when to use '\' instead of '/' or when a '\\' is applicable.

This time there is '\' in paths as the makefile gets generated from a VS .vxproj via a Perl script.

Strange thing is now that a 100% working makefile behaves different on another machine running exactly the same make.exe binary which is part of my repository.

A rule like this

```
$(OBJ_DIR)\Atomics.obj : ..\BSW\Atomics\src\Atomics.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<
```

on the other machine produces the error message

```
Cannot open source file: '..BSWAtomicssrcAtomics.c'
```

OK, solution is make Perl toggle the '\' into '/' when creating the makefile.

**But still I wonder if there is some Windows setting which causes this problem?**

In a cmd.exe in same directory the same make.exe is called just like:

```
D:\project\XYZ\make>..\tool\make\make.exe
```

Comment: It may have to do with (possibly) a different compiler, in which one of them interprets backslashes as escape, and in the other, as directory separators.

Comment: Looking at the make debug output (-d) I realized that on the other machine a *NIX shell (sh.exe) is asked to execute the commands. I kinda forgot this that GNU make has some internal "strategy" to find a shell if not otherwise given to it via SHELL=.
So on my main machine there is no sh.exe - thats why make.exe was forced to use cmd.exe which of course understands the blackslash...

Comment: @vl106 If you feel like you have found an answer remember to post it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed the presence of some shell binary (msys, mingw, etc.) broke my makefile for the other host. So the only way for my makefile to stick to its  MS-DOS commands is to hide the UN*X tools by PATH-settings (e.g. start sub-shell with mini environment).